# Socket intermittently reads only 1448/2896 bytes

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream, apache-commons-io

I am using Commons-IO to read and write from Socket. Things all works till payload size is either 1448/2896 max.

Below is the code snippet. Really unsure how to handle it.
Checked system buffer size too

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
4096    16384   4194304
```

```
public static void usingCommonsIO(){
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(serverIP, 55000);
        IOUtils.write(request.getBytes(), socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Message Sent....");
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String resp =IOUtils.toString(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(resp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Alternatively tried using DataInputStream but no luck. Code snipped is below.

```
public static void usingDataIOStream(String requestStr){
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.6", 55000);
        System.out.println("Request Length -:" + request.length());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.write(requestStr.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, requestStr.length());
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Message Sent....");
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        byte[] response = new byte[16*1024];
        int responseLength = din.read(response);
        System.out.println("Response -:" + new java.lang.String(response, 0, responseLength));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Confusing part is that the same code works with only 1448 bytes sometimes and max of 2896 bytes sometimes. There are no specific patterns.

**Update 1**

To simulate it, tried writing Server socket on my own and code is as below. Strange thing noticed with this is, on first request payload of size 6500 was read and received properly. Connection Reset from second request onwards. Am I missing something here?

```
public static void usingBAOS() throws IOException {

    server = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream din = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting  for Client...");
        try {
            // Accepting Client's connection
            socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connnected to client " + socket.getInetAddress());
            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            // Read request payload from Socket
            String requestString = readRequest(din);
            System.out.println("Request Read.....");
            System.out.println("Writing Response.....");
            // Writing response to socket
            dos = writeResponse(socket, requestString);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            //close resources
            din.close();
            System.out.println("InputStream is closed......");
            dos.close();
            System.out.println("OutputStream is closed......");
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Socket is closed......");
        }
    }
}

private static DataOutputStream writeResponse(Socket socket, String requestString) throws IOException {
    String responseString = "Hi Client" + requestString;

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    //write object to Socket
    dos.write(responseString.getBytes(),0, responseString.getBytes().length);
    dos.flush();
    return dos;
}

private static String readRequest(DataInputStream din) throws IOException {
    byte[] response = new byte[16*1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int n = 0;
    boolean read = true;
    while(read){
        n = din.read(response);
        baos.write(response, 0, n);
        if(baos.toString().length() == n){
            read = false;
        }
    }
    baos.flush();
    String requestString = baos.toString();
    return requestString;
}
```

Comment: Your code using `DataInputStream` is wrong. There's no guarantee that a single `read(byte[])` will read all data. The return value indicates how many bytes were read.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the input. Tried but didnt work.    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int n = 0;
    while((n = din.read(response) )!= -1){
       baos.write(response, 0, n);
    }

Comment: You mean you get the same behaviour? Can it be a problem on the server side? Have you tried on other computers?

Comment: Yes, still the same behaviour. It is a third party service. Suspected to be a problem on the server side, but they claim that other clients are able to consume without any such issues.

Comment: Two problems with this question: 1) you are implementing a protocol, but you haven't provided a specification for it. We have to infer the protocol from your code, but that's obviously not going to help diagnose an incorrect implementation; 2) you never say what the problem is. You hint that something goes wrong, but offer no clue what that is.

Comment: @JamesKPolk 1) Working with TCP/IP protocol to send and receive requests and responses. 2) The problem is, if payload length is less than or equal to 1448 bytes, everything works normal. Moment response sent from server is more than 1448 bytes, response bytes read is either 1448 or 2896 bytes only.

Comment: He meant the application protocol, not the underlying wire protocol. Although the `1448` size does hint at the problem being [lower than in the application protocol](https://blog.apnic.net/2014/12/15/ip-mtu-and-tcp-mss-missmatch-an-evil-for-network-performance/).

Comment: The application protocol used is ISO8583. ISO8583 format messages are read and written over sockets. Thanks for sharing the link, does it end up tuning IP MTU? If yes, payload size more than 1448 bytes are working intermittently(2 out of 4 times) which is a weird behaviour.

Comment: I guess this is a dead question but out of interest I'm having the same problem using sockets between two Android 8.0 devices. If I try to send more than 1448 bytes of data, the client only receives 1448 despite calling `read(byte[], 0, 2560)`. Bytes >1448 received appear to be junk. Find it hard to believe that `write(byte[], 0, 2560)` doesn't try to send multiple packets if there is a payload limit of 1448.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old at the time of writing this answer I'm putting this here for others in case it solves their problem. I encountered the same issue when using buffered data input and output streams on Android 8.0 devices where I had naively assumed that doing this:

```
int len = 2304;
byte[] data = new byte[len];
inputStream.read(data, 0, len);
```

would read all the data I sent down the socket. But as suggested by @Kayaman in the comments, this does not guarantee that `len` bytes of data are actually read from the buffer even if there are bytes available. In fact, this is in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

> `public final int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException`
>
> Reads up to `len` bytes of data from the contained input stream into an array of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read, possibly zero. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.

In fact, if it doesn't read all the data, the only way to tell is to capture the returned value. My solution was then to monitor the amount of bytes actually read from the stream and just call `read()` in a loop as:

```
int i = 0;
len = 2304;
byte[] data = new byte[len];
while (i < len)
{
    i += socket.inputStream.read(data, i, len - i);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.